# How to programmatically remove a menu context item in Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2013

I have an Outlook add in that was written with Outlook 2010 in mind but I am updating to handle Outlook 2013 correctly.  As part of the add in I have included a number of context menu buttons using the IRibbon method.

At this point these new menu items work correctly, however I wish to remove one of the default Outlook contxt menu buttons with right clicking on a mail item or document in a specific folder.

I have tried declaring a GetVisible event for the button in the Ribbon XML but this does not get fired like the GetVisibile calls I have for my new custom added buttons.

If anyone has any hints, tips or experience with disabling one of the default Outlook 2013 context menu options they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share how you removed existing options from the contextmenu for a folder

Comment: Hi imasud.  For some of the options you can remove them using Ribbon.InvalidateControlMso, but for some, like Delete this is not possible, so you have to intercept the behaviour of the option and manually stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into this further, the "Delete" option I was looking to remove was a new addition on 2013, having originally thought the add in I was working with had removed it in 2010.

It shares the same behaviour as the "Delete" button in the main top ribbon and appears to be a menu item that cannot be removed on an item type basis, but you can suppress the behaviour of the button within the add in.